# In a linear regressio model using scikit, how does the confusion matrix know which is the positive class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am performing a cancer prediction task (where 1 is cancer case and 0 is a control). The tutorials I've watched never seem to indicate to the Logistic Regression model which is the positive class to eventually produce the confusion matrix.

Is it by default that the true positives will display the '1's correctly predicted and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` we have a parameter called `labels` with default value `None`. The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) of `labels` tells us:

> List of labels to index the matrix. This may be used to reorder or
> select a subset of labels. If `None` is given, those that appear at
> least once in y_true or y_pred are used in **sorted order**.

So to assign proper index to your classes, pass them sequentially to `labels`
Say for example positive = 1, negative = 0

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm
>>> y_test = [1, 0, 0]
>>> y_pred = [1, 0, 0]
>>> cm(y_test, y_pred, labels=[1,0])
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 2]])

              Pred
             |  pos=1 | neg=0 |
         ___________________
Actual  pos=1|  TP=1  | FN=0 |
        neg=0|  FP=0  | TN=2 |
```

**Note:** The TP,TN,FP and FN have changed places by passing labels as [1,0]. TP means both predicted and actual value are positive. TN means both predicted and actual value are negative.Same analysis can be done for FP and FN.

If we dont pass any value to `labels`, the y_true and y_pred values will be used in sorted order i.e [0,1].

```
>>> y_test = [1, 0, 0]
>>> y_pred = [1, 0, 0]
>>> cm(y_test, y_pred)
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1]])
                 Pred
             |  neg=0 | pos=1 |
         ___________________
Actual  neg=0|  TN=2  | FP=0 |
        pos=1|  FN=0  | TN=1 |
```

This will become even more clear if we use more than 2 labels. Cat=1, Dog=2, Mouse=3
If you want the order to be Cat, Mouse, and Dog then labels=[1,3,2]

```
>>> y_test = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y_pred = [1, 3, 2]
>>> cm(y_test, y_pred, labels=[1,3,2])
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])

                Pred
          |  1  |  3  |  2 |
          __________________
Actual  1 |   1 |  0  |  0 |
        3 |   0 |  0  |  1 |
        2 |   0 |  1  |  0 |
```

If you want some other order like Dog,Mouse, and Cat then labels=[2,3,1]

```
>>> cm(y_test, y_pred, labels=[2,3,1])
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply @MSS

Comment: This answer is not correct, the order of tp/tn is backwards. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Comment: `cm[0][0]` should be the number of **true negatives**.

Comment: @Alexander : True positives and true negatives are to be derived based on the predicted and true label indices. Its position can change based on  the labels passed. Care to explain with another answer? I will delete mine if you can explain logically.

Comment: This is so close to being a good answer that I want you to fix it. Take a look at the first listing in this answer, and compare with: `tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()` shown in the documentation.

Comment: Please try to understand my answer with `labels` documentation. The code mentioned by you doesn't use `labels`, hence they are sorted as [0,1]. I am explicitly passing them as[1,0].Hence tn and tp have changed places.

Comment: Forgive me: I was talking past you and that was rude of me. I edited this answer to show the conventional case with 0/1. My issue was that the other interpretation of passing `labels=[1,0]` is that it flips the interpretation, so I think we were arriving at the same problem from two perspectives.